# Drawing a line and getting the length of the line C#?

Tags: c#, mapwindow, dotspatial

I am trying to get the length of a drawn line to a textbox but its throwing an NullReferenceException at *var length = f.ToShape().ToGeometry().Length;*.
what else should i use in the code to finish this exception. ?
Any way to fix it and get the length of the line to a textbox?
I am using Dot-Spatial 1.70

Code:

```
private void map1_MouseClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // digitizing
        if (amDigitizing == true)
        {
            DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c = new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate();
            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point();
            p.X = e.X;
            p.Y = e.Y;
            c = map1.PixelToProj(p);

            myDigitizedPoints.Add(c);
        }
    }
    private void map1_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Double click ends digitizing
        if (amDigitizing == true)
        {
            DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c = new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate();
            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point();
            p.X = e.X;
            p.Y = e.Y;
            c = map1.PixelToProj(p);
            myDigitizedPoints.Add(c);

            amDigitizing = false;


            DotSpatial.Data.Feature f = new DotSpatial.Data.Feature(DotSpatial.Topology.FeatureType.Line, myDigitizedPoints);
            DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet fs = new DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet();
            fs.AddFeature(f);

            fs.Projection = map1.Projection;
            fs.Name = "Mine";
            //fs.SaveAs(GraphicsPathExt, true);
            //LineLyr = (DotSpatial.Controls.MapLineLayer)map1.AddLayer(GraphicsPathExt);
            LineLyr = (MapLineLayer)map1.Layers.Add(fs);

            var length = f.ToShape().ToGeometry().Length;
            textBox1.Text = length.ToString();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

so finally i am able to find it on my own. 
posting it for new users like me who struggles alot using 3rd party tools.

Here i want to confess that there is no direct way of finding the length of the line feature in Dot-Spatial. One need to do it through a hard-way using the basic Distance Equation.

Code i used:

```
   IRaster r = (IRaster)map1.Layers[0].DataSet;

        IFeatureSet fs = LineLyr.DataSet;

        int np = 0;

        try
        {
            foreach (IFeature f in fs.Features)
            {
                np += f.Coordinates.Count * 100;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }



        foreach (IFeature f in fs.Features)
        {
            foreach (DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c in f.Coordinates)
            {
                x2 = c.X;
                y2 = c.Y;
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    dx = (x2 - x1) / 100;
                    dy = (y2 - y1) / 100;

                    newx = x1;
                    newy = y1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    {
                        TotalLength += Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dx, 2) + Math.Pow(dy, 2));

                        z = demLyr.DataSet.GetNearestValue(newx, newy);
                        //plotX[i] = TotalLength;
                        //plotY[i] = z;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(TotalLength.ToString());
                }
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;


                if (i == 0)
                {
                    z = demLyr.DataSet.GetNearestValue(newx, newy);
                    plotX[i] = TotalLength;
                    plotY[i] = z;
                    i += 1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                }
            }
        }
```